# javascript regex to remove a substring from string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have the following url

```
example.com/p/deals&post_id=3
```

where post id is a get variable. I would like to sanitize the url string and the returned result should  be

```
example.com/p/deals
```

I have been trying to use JavaScript's `.replace` but because of the get variable at the end of url, doesn't seems to work. How would I build a regex to exclude this substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex is not needed for this. Simply [split the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and take the first string from the array:

```
var str = "example.com/p/deals&post_id=3";
var san = str.split("&")[0];
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/ks4gH/).

Answer (score 3):

To match all chars after and including the first & you would use the pattern

> \&(.*)

and simply replace with an empty string.

the JS would be

```
var urlString = "example.com/p/deals&post_id=3";
var searchP = "\&(.*)" ;
var replaceP = "" ;
var rEx = new RegExp( searchP, urlString ) ;
var replacedText = sourceText.replace( rEx, replaceP ) ;
```